# Error when clicking on element

Tags: java, selenium

I am not able to click on an element in selenium web driver getting error:

```
Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stack trace information)
```

This problem is only on IE and everything works fine on Firefox.

I used `isDisplayed()` function but it's not showing element. Maybe opacity of the element is zero?

Comment: Can you share where it happened? Website? It might be due to element now visible or loctor might be denoting more than one element.

Comment: You already explained your own question. If the element is not visible, you cannot click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is not visible you cannot click on it through normal ways. You could execute a javascript script to click on it though.

```java
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to fact that object was not loaded yet, you can wait until button is displayed.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("id"))).click();
```